# Erro 13 Tipos Incompativeis

Tags: excel-vba

Minha planilha da esse erro toda vez que tento setar para a coluna 3 de uma tabela aparecer na minha `listview`. Acho que sei qual `"=PROCV([@Item];PRODUTO;6;0)"` e a `listview` está configurada para receber um texto normal.

Codigo VBA:

```
Private Sub Atualizar()

Dim Item As ListItem

Dim LinhaFinal As Integer

Dim i As Integer

valoresmanun.ListItems.Clear

LinhaFinal = Planilha14.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 7 To LinhaFinal
    
valoresmanun.ListItems.Add Text:=Planilha14.Cells(i, 2)
    
Set Item = valoresmanun.ListItems.AddPlanilha14.Cells(i, 2)
 
    

Next
 

End Sub
```

Comment: Boa tarde! Seja bem-vindo ao fórum! Para podermos te ajudar, precisamos que melhore o título da sua pergunta e o texto dela. Veja estes links: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-sopt-vers%c3%a3o-curta?cb=1 e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1

Comment: @rtheodoro: [O Stack Overflow não é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387), somos um [site de perguntas e respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/137387).

Comment: Não estou ao computador, mas acho que ```Cells(i, 2)``` retorna um objeto do tipo Range, enquanto o método ```Lisitems.Add``` requer um  parâmetro String. Provavelmente você resolve isso usando ```valoresmanun.ListItems.Add Text:=Planilha14.Cells(i, 2).Text``` (ou talvez .Value).

Comment: MAS a melhor forma de resolver é outra. Você pode povoar a Listview passando a range inteira, sem precisar iterar. Não lembro o método agora, assim que chegar em casa te digo.